# Defining a type cast in Java

Tags: java, types, casting

I want to define a type cast from an arbitrary type to a primitive data type in Java. Is it possible to define a cast from one arbitrary type to another arbitrary type?

```
public class Foo{
    //methods, constructor etc for this class
    ...
    //make it possible to cast an object of type Foo to an integer 
}
//example of how an object of type foo would be cast to an integer
public class Bar(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        int int1 = (int)foo1;
        System.out.println(int1+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fairly sure this is not possible, but perhaps someone can correct me on this.

Comment: Cant there be a struct like cast, as long as the Classes have the same variables?

Comment: @LeeScott no, Java would throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: Actually what do you want to acheive with this casting.....You want to cast a reference of a class with its own methods and feilds to an `int`..Why???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't cast it, but you can provide a conversion function:

```
public class Foo{
    //methods, constructor etc for this class
    ...
    public int toInt(){
        //convert to an int.
    }    
}
```

Bar then becomes:

```
public class Bar(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        int int1 = foo1.toInt();
        System.out.println(int1+"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to convert from a class type (eg. Foo) to a primitive type directly. Instead you should define methods (eg. `int asInteger()`) that return the value of a Foo object as an integer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. It wouldn't really make sense: how could a `Foo` become an `int`?

Rather define a sequence of appropriate methods, such as:

```
public int toInt() { return 42; }
```

Typecasting between primitive types and Java types, such as between `int` and `Integer`, was not even originally part of Java.

Answer (score 1):

class Foo must extend Number. Why would you want to do that though? why not just access an int variable inside of foo.